# Finding bases for subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$ and extending them to bases of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am given the following question:

> For each of the sets in Problem 1 which is a subspace of  $\mathbb R^3$, find a basis for the subspace, and then extend it to a basis for  $\mathbb R^3$.

We found that in Problem 1, the following subspaces are:

- $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x = 0\}$
- $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x + y = 0\}$
- $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x = y = z\}$

(Reference: [Determine whether each of the following subsets of $\mathbb R^3$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261320/determine-whether-each-of-the-following-subsets-of-mathbb-r3-is-a-subspace-o))

How do I answer the above question?

We know that $\{i, j, k\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^3$ where
$i = (1,0,0)$, $j = (0,1,0)$, $k = (0,0,1)$. If $u = (1,1,1)$ then
$\operatorname{span} \{ i, j, k, u \} = \mathbb R^3$.

I don't know how to relate it to the subspaces in Problem 1!

Comment: Can you say what those subspaces look like, what their elements look like?

Comment: Let W = {(x,y,z)$\in$$\mathbb R^3$ : x = 0}. Let $w_1$ = (0,y,z), $w_2$=(0,y2,z2). Then $w_1+w_2$ = (0, y1+y2, z1+z2)

Comment: So every element of the first looks like $y(0,1,0)+z(0,0,1)$. Now what about the second subspace?

Comment: @user4640007 Do you understand what these subspaces represent geometrically? This can greatly help understanding this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And note in basic terms, the number of vectors in the basis is the dimension of that subspace.

$S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} | x=0\}$

So this is no different then vectors of the form $(0,y,z)$

so a basis could be the set of $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ for example.

ie, $\mathbb{B}=\{(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ ie a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$

For $S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} | x+y=0 \}$

$x+y=0$ is the same as saying $y=-x$

ie vectors of the form $(x,-x,z)$

so a basis could be,

$\mathbb{B}=\{(1,-1,0) ,(0,0,1)\}$  Another two dimensional subspace

For $S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} | x=y=z \}$

This one I think is more intuitive,
it will be vectors of the form $(z,z,z)$ for example. So its just a one dimensional subspace with $\mathbb{B}=(1,1,1)$

Comment: The basis for the second would be $\{(1,-1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.

Comment: Thanks it is ever more clear

Comment: @user4640007  Thats good. So yea these problems really consist of just this. find a way to represent one of the variables in terms of the other etc. Then just use the definition of a basis